# Hadoop distributed cache : using -libjars : How to use external jars in your code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

Okay I am able to add external jars to my code using ilibjars path.
Now how to use those external jars in my code. say I have a function defined in that jar which operates on String. How to use it.
using context.getArchiveClassPaths(), i can get a path to it but i don't know how to instantiate that object.

here is the sample jar class that i am importing

```
package replace;

public class ReplacingAcronyms {

    public static String Replace(String abc){
        String n;
        n="This is trial";
        return n;
}

}





public class wc_runner extends Configured implements Tool {
        @Override
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(new Configuration());
        job.setJarByClass(wc_runner.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(wc_mapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(wc_reducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(wc_reducer.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

        return (job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);


        }        

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new wc_runner(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

**commands ran**

```
[training@localhost Desktop]$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=file:///home/training/Desktop/replace.jar 
[training@localhost Desktop]$ hadoop jar try1.jar wc_runner /user/training/MR/custom/trial1 /user/training/MR/custom/out -libjars ./replace.jar
```

**error**

```
14/03/08 02:39:40 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the    arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/03/08 02:39:41 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/03/08 02:39:41 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/03/08 02:39:41 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/03/08 02:39:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201403080114_0021
14/03/08 02:39:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/08 02:39:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201403080114_0021_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: replace.ReplacingAcronyms
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190
```

Comment: Okay, I was using the wrong command.. after using this.

hadoop jar try.jar wc_runner /user/training/MR/custom/trial1 /user/training/MR/custom/out -libjars replace.jar

Now its giving unresolved compilation error, because while writing in java, i did not put replace package in the same package as my code and code is giving "cannot be resolved" But I am trying to put this package through distributed cache. 

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Import your package to your mapred code then add your jar file's path in HADOOP_CLASSPATH before running your mapred job.

E.g.
In your mapred java

```
import your.external.package;
```

On compilation

```
javac -cp /path/to/your/external/package.jar:...
```

On running the hadoop jar

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/your/external/package.jar
hadoop jar yourmapred.jar your.class -libjar /path/to/your/external/package.jar ....
```

Comment: If i import my package, then that will be included while creating jar for my map-reduce code. But i want to include my external jar through -libjars command.

Comment: No,it doesnt necessarily mean you need to include your package on your mapred job jar file,you just need to include it on the javac classpath during compilation. Then do the hadoop_classpath thing when you do hadoop jar -libjar.

Comment: can u show me the command to include it in classpath. I am writing my code in java eclipse and not able to understand the process

Comment: Ok. I tried that but still I am getting an error. Can you please take a look at my runner class and commands ran?.

Comment: Can you try omitting the file://

Comment: Also by adding jars through libjars, doesn't hadoop itself adds the file to its classpath

Comment: Try putting -libjars argument after the classname,that is,before your own custom arguments

Comment: Illegal Argument Exception