# Hadoop with mongoDB : NoClassDefFoundError MongoConfigUtil

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, mongodb-hadoop

I'm learning how to write a map / reduce job in hadoop with mongodb data as input. So I followed [this](http://www.javased.com/?source_dir=mongo-hadoop/examples/wordcount/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/examples/wordcount/WordCount.java) example,  but I got following error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/hadoop/util/MongoConfigUtil
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I've been searching for hours without any result. Any one can help me please.

Comment: have you tried -libjars options ? see this as an example https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Comment: pom.xml is not visible. its very difficult to understand and answer what is missing how you are deploying

Answer (score 1):

it means `mongo-hadoop-core.jar` is available at compile time but not at run time.

Try running your application with dependency jars added in classpath

Example : `java -cp mongo-hadoop-core.jar<++other dependencies> MainClass`

**EDIT 1**

If you're running using `hadoop` shell

check the `classpath` by executing `hadoop classpath` it will print the dir/jars in the classpath.

If the dependent jars are not in the classpath add them  in the `classpath` using `export` command then execute `hadoop jar yourjar.jar mainClass`

**EDIT 2**

make use of `libjars` option

`hadoop jar myjar.jar mainClass -libjars ${LIBJARS}`

Comment: The problem is that in hadoop we should extract the jar from the application and execute it with "hadoop jar name.jar className" so i don't know how to  include other jars with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this link examples folder structure is maven. I CANT see pom.xml in that link.

We can set maven scope from `provided` to `runtime`

1. You need to write [assembly.xml](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html) (to package your application lib and related dependencies in tar file) and need to refer it from pom.xml to package mongo-hadoop-core.jar along with other dependencies which are **NOT** installed in cluster.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`:`hbase classpath`
```

```
hadoop jar .... -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH MainClass
```

If you unzip the tar file mentioned above and you can refer the classpath for example : 
hadoop jar ....  ../lib/* main classs
where lib folder contails all your dependencies like your mongodb also.

2. If mongo db and related components are installed in the cluster we can mention the *classpath* like below example.

Also see this answer how they have used [`libjars`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245425/hadoop-distributed-cache-using-libjars-how-to-use-external-jars-in-your-cod)